# Буфер фиксированной длины в FormatMessage

Tags: c, winapi

*FormatMessage* в Win10 при использовании *FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER* для освобождения выделенного буфера требует использования *HeapFree*, а в ранних версиях - *LocalFree*. Подумав, пришел к такому варианту:

```
VOID GetWin32Error() {
  TCHAR buff[0x100]; // буфер фиксированного размера
  _tprintf(TEXT("%ls\n"), !FormatMessage(
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS |
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_MAX_WIDTH_MASK, NULL, GetLastError(), 
    MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), buff,
    sizeof(buff) - sizeof(TCHAR), // нужен ли нуль-терминатор?
    NULL
  ) ? TEXT("Unknown error.") : msg);
}
```

Знаю, что длина сообщения может быть более указанного, но это только для примера. Собственно, нужно ли отнимать от общего числа байт *TCHAR* место под нуль-терминатор или все же достаточно *sizeof(TCHAR)*? Если же все-таки лучше использовать динамическое выделение буфера, как унифицировать освобождение буфера? Условная компиляция, макрос, что?

Comment: Функция `HeapFree` - требует указать heap-handle (которая вам не извесна). Ф-ция `LocalFree` подставляет всегда правильный handle, пробрасывает параметры и делает вызов  `HeapFree`. Т.е. `LocalFree(x)` еквивалентно `HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(),0,x)`. И так и так можно, но я бы предпочёл первое.

Comment: Если буфер фиксированной длины, _nSize_ должен быть ```sizeof(buff) / sizeof(buff[0])```, - размер буфера и количество байт в буфере все же разные вещи.

Answer (score 0):

По порядку:

> FormatMessage в Win10 при использовании FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER
>   для освобождения выделенного буфера требует использования HeapFree, а
>   в ранних версиях - LocalFree.

Откуда появился этот странный вывод? В документации сказано совсем другое. Конкретно там сказано, что поскольку `FormatMessage` вызывает `LocalAlloc` с флагом `LMEM_FIXED`, то в Win10 для освобождения этого буфера можно использовать `HeapFree`. То есть это значит, что в Windows 10 `LMEM_FIXED` реализуется через функции `Heap*`, вот и все. Лучше не обращать на это внимание и по-прежнему освобождать буфер через `LocalFree`, иначе в предыдущих версиях Windows программа работать не будет.

> Собственно, нужно ли отнимать от общего числа байт TCHAR место под
>   нуль-терминатор или все же достаточно sizeof(TCHAR)?

Нужно указывать общий размер буфера в `TCHAR`, так что отнимать ничего не нужно.

> Если же все-таки лучше использовать динамическое выделение буфера, как
>   унифицировать освобождение буфера? Условная компиляция, макрос, что?

Лучше использовать `FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER`. Как сказано выше, никаких условных компиляций и макросов не нужно, просто освобождайте буфер через `LocalFree`, как и раньше.